# Regex (JS) : character appears no more than N times

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string :

```
11110000111100000000111100001111000000
```

In this string, I would like to replace the `0`s that appear less than 6 times one after the other. If they appear 6 times or more, I would like to keep them.

(Replace them with a dot for instance)

The end result should then be

```
1111....1111000000001111....1111000000
```

I thought about using the negative lookahead and tried it, but I'm not sure how it works in that particular use-case.

Would someone be able to help me ?

My current, not working regex is

```
/(?!0{6,})0{1,5}/g
```

**EDIT**

After playing around a bit, I found this regex :

```
/((?:^|1)(?!0{6,})0{1,5})/g
```

but it captures the `1` before the `0`s. Would there be a way to exclude this `1` from getting caught in the regex ?

Comment: Please also show the javascript you're using

Comment: There's no Javascript involved yet. I'm just trying to match the regex. I use [regex101](https://regex101.com/) to test it.

Comment: I say it's Javascript because regexes differ according to the language used.

Comment: So you want to replace fewer than 6 consecutive `0`s with as many dots?

Comment: I think the most elegant solution here would be to replace `0+` with a custom replacement function that checks the length of the match and returns either the match (no replacement) or as many dots as the match is long.

Comment: @MGX You can also match those zeros by e.g. [`(1|^)(0{1,5})(?=1|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/RMVm45/1) but it does not look like that would help you much as you don't want the `1` in the match it seems. However you could also use [this one with a replace callback (demo)](https://tio.run/##TY1BCsIwEEX3OcUshEwwpk1BEEr1JkIoQ1WSpiSxm7Znj@lC9MEwnw9v5mVmE/vwnNJpvuRsKUGEDrgu1IXv/s@/jreM7UqgXYoq0GRNT1ihXu8C60XL8ybw1un1IKpBArpaOi1dI6C7wsKgqOkdRnAa4Ahc8f0GmYSuUZbGIT1Ey7YyrPdj9JaU9QOWf6LN@QM).

Comment: @LMD I did that with an exec loop to get the length. Replacing was not the issue, getting the strings to replace with the regex was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Javascript, if a positive lookbehind is supported and with the global flag:

```
/(?<=(?:1|^)(?!0{6})0{0,4})0/g
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<=` Positive lookbehind, assert to the left

  - `(?:1|^)` Match either 1 or start of the string
  - `(?!0{6})` Negative lookahead, assert not 6 zeroes
  - `0{0,4}` Match 0-4 times a zero
- `)` Close the lookbehind
- `0` Match a zero

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PJIAq8/1)

In the replacement use a dot.

Comment: This is ... a very nice one! !!

Comment: Pretty nice! PS: I would just use `[^0]` instead of `(?:1|^)`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Thanks, I used 1 because the example strings have 0 and 1, but you could use that as well to broaden the scope.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know positive look behinds existed ! Quick question though, would it be better to use a negative look ahead at the end, instead of the `0` you put ?

Comment: Oh sorry I got it backwards, the end `0` is actually the one being replaced, it's not a boundary. Ignore my question !

Answer (score 5):

Javascript [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace?retiredLocale=de) can take a function as replacement, e.g.:

```
let res = s.replace(/0+/g, m => {
  return (x = m.length) < 6 ? '.'.repeat(x) : m;
});
```

[See this demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##TYxBDsIgFET3nGJ2QFRaN8aI1bMQ8oMaCg1g08R4dqQLo7OZn5n/5mFmk226T2U3H2v1VJAxgO@b@qav/9@/jGvGViTRCmWVaPLGkuj6Tee2GDFc8GJofXmmALG0r1F5Cq7cJM444Aqu@MqRKWKROGHU7C3bro0hR0/KRyfavtS1fgA)

There is not much to explain. Matching one or more `0`. If the match is below 6 characters, return a string composed of its length repeated replacement character, else return the full match.

Comment: just curious where did the x come from? like we are not supposed to use uninitialised vars normally no?

Comment: @riskylast the x is assigned in `(x = m.length)` I'm not sure if this is ugly, not doing much in JS :)

Comment: I've been doing js for 10 years and I didn't even think of it ... You humbled me, thank you !

Comment: (and the syntax is correct, `x` can just be declared above that)

Comment: I am sorry but I have to give the +15 to thee other answer, I wish I could mark both as the right one, but he answered my exact question and not a workaround (although totally valid, and this is the one I am using) ...

Comment: That's absolutely fine @MGX I love the other answer as well! ✔️ though there might be temorary compatibility issues due to lack of lookbehind support 